# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bounding_box' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Currently, I am trying to load all my tweets from the keywords which i search. There are 10 results actually but I am being shown only 3 results and in my console window its showing an error message.

This is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bounding_box' of null
```

This is my js code:

```
(function(){
    var location = new Array();
    var query = '%23CM0655';
    var url = "search.php";
    $.post(url, {query:query}, function(tweets){
        console.log(tweets);
        $("#tweetResult tbody").html("");
        var geoEnabled = false;
        var placeName = "";
        var countryName = "";

        for(var i=0; i<tweets.statuses.length; i++){
            var row = $("<tr></tr>");
            var img = $("<td><div class='div_pic'><img src='" + tweets.statuses[i].user.profile_image_url + "' class='tweetpic'/>"+
                        "<label class='user_name' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name+"</label>"+
                        "<label class='divlatitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0]+"</label>"+
                        "<label class='divlongtitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][1]+"</label>"+
                        "</div></td>");
            //var img = $("<td><div class='div_pic'><img src='" + tweets.statuses[i].user.profile_image_url + "' class='tweetpic'/></div></td>");
            row.append(img);
              // row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name));

            row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name));
            row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].text + "<br/>"));
            geoEnabled = tweets.statuses[i].user.geo_enabled;
            if(geoEnabled){
                placeName = tweets.statuses[i].place.name;
                countryName = tweets.statuses[i].place.country;
                if(placeName != null){
                    row.append($("<td></td>").html(placeName + "," + countryName + "<br/>"));
                }
                row.append($("<td></td>").html("Location: " + tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0] + ", " + 
                    tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][1] + "<br/>"));
                row.append($("<td></td>").html(tweets.statuses[i].created_at));
            }
            $("#tweetResult tbody").append(row)

        }
    });

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

This is the line which is showing the error:

```
 "<label class='divlatitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0]+"</label>"+
```

Are there any way to solve this error. I want to show all the tweets even the location is not enabled for the certain tweets. Can someone help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following `tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0]` to

```
tweets.statuses[i].place ? tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0] : "No location data"
```

Since you are using this snippet at multiple places, i would suggest you to store that in a variable and use it.

In general if you the data object you get can have `null` or `undefined`, it is always better to play safe. The above code can be like:

```
var location = (tweets.statuses[i].place && tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box && tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0] ) || "No location";
```

Assuming,  if you have `bounding_box`, you will surely be having `coordinates[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a if-else statement around it

```
if (tweets.statuses[i].user.geo_enabled && tweets.statuses[i].place != null) {

                var img = $("<td><div class='div_pic'><img src='" + tweets.statuses[i].user.profile_image_url + "' class='tweetpic'/>"+
                            "<label class='user_name' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name+"</label>"+
                            "<label class='divlatitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][0]+"</label>"+
                            "<label class='divlongtitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0][1]+"</label>"+
                            "</div></td>");
            }else{

                var img = $("<td><div class='div_pic'><img src='" + tweets.statuses[i].user.profile_image_url + "' class='tweetpic'/>"+
                    "<label class='user_name' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].user.screen_name+"</label>"+
                    "<label class='divlatitude' hidden>null</label>"+
                    "<label class='divlongtitude' hidden>"+tweets.statuses[i].user.location+"</label>"+
                    "</div></td>");
            }
```